# SLF4J NoSuchMethodError at Log4JLoggerAdapter

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j, wildfly

I am having this exception:

```
org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.format(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
    at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter.info(Log4jLoggerAdapter.java:341)
    at org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog.info(Slf4jLog.java:67)
    at org.mortbay.log.Log.<clinit>(Log.java:79)
    at com.goodgamestudios.icosphere.service.FileReader.XLSFileReader.extractRowValuesAsStringArray(XLSFileReader.java:79)
    at com.goodgamestudios.icosphere.service.FileReader.XLSFileReader.extractHeaders(XLSFileReader.java:84)
    at com.goodgamestudios.icosphere.service.FileReader.XLSFileReader.getDataFromFile(XLSFileReader.java:40)
    at com.goodgamestudios.icosphere.service.FileReaderAndWriter.FileReaderAndWriterTest.testReader(FileReaderAndWriterTest.java:101)
    at com.goodgamestudios.icosphere.service.FileReaderAndWriter.FileReaderAndWriterTest.testExcelReader(FileReaderAndWriterTest.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:46)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:18)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
```

This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.goodgamestudios</groupId>
    <artifactId>Icosphere</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>Icosphere Data Platform</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>mapr-releases</id>
            <url>http://repository.mapr.com/maven/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss</id>
            <name>JBoss repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mapr.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>maprfs</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2-mapr</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mapr.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>maprfs-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3-mapr-2.1.3.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>  
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>  
            <version>5.2</version>  
        </dependency>         
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-auth</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
            <version>0.94.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>18.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
            <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cloudera.htrace</groupId>
            <artifactId>htrace-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.05</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jruby.joni</groupId>
            <artifactId>joni</artifactId>   
            <version>2.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-se</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.14.Final</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-ejb_3.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>deltaspike-core-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.cdictrl</groupId>
            <artifactId>deltaspike-cdictrl-weld</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-client</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-remote-naming</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.xnio</groupId>
            <artifactId>xnio-nio</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.11-beta2</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>-->

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipAssembly>true</skipAssembly>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>secondPartTestsExecution</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

After reading a lot similiar problems, I also made sure that there are no libs from logback or common-logging (I tried to use those before) in the lib-folder of the wildfly Application server I am using.

What a I not seeing?

Regards and thanks for the help!

Comment: This looks like a surefire issue to me. Or well maybe maven. This is coming from a test not WildFly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that any of the libraries you use in your project relies in a diferent slf4j version that the one you provide.

Comment: And is there a way for me to find out which depndencies are used by the libraries?

Comment: There are different tools to see dependencies in a whole project. I usually use Eclipse's pom viewer, in Dependency Hierachy view. There you can search slf4j and eclipse filters all references to this library and the versions that are used.

Comment: For WildFly 9.x it's [1.7.7.jbossorg-1](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-core/blob/1.0.1.Final/pom.xml#L127)

Comment: http://wiki.netbeans.org/MavenBestPractices
See paragraph "Dependency Management"

Answer (score 0):

It  mainly caused by the different versions of `SLF4j` introduced by you in the  project `lib` folder. If you are using **Maven** check your `pom.xml` , if you introduce more than one `SLF4j`.